# How to fetch data from two tables in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

This is table1:

```
product_id|product_desc|product_name|product_s_desc
```

This is table2:

```
product_price_id|product_id|product_price
```

Now I want to fetch data from these tables. `product_id` is same in both tables.

I want to fetch

1. `product_s_desc`
2. `product_desc`
3. `product_name` AND `product_price` from other table.

Please help me do this.

Comment: Sorry! table2 also have product_price

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a field named `product_price` in your second table (you didn't list it):

```
SELECT t1.product_s_desc, t1.product_desc, t1.product_name, t2.product_price
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.product_id = t1.product_id
```

You should check out the MySQL manual regarding [`JOINS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), as this is a very basic part of writing SQL queries.  You might also consider adding an index on `table2` for the product_id field to make the query run faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from table1 join table2 on table1.productid = table2.productid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.product_price  
FROM table1 t1,table2 t2 
WHERE t1.product_id=t2.product_id
```

Answer (score -4):

```
$sql = "SELECT Student.First_Name,Student.Last_name,Student.Mobile_No,Student.Email,Student.Institue,Student.DOB,Student.Gender
            Address.Address_Line1,Address.City,Address.State,Address.Country,Address.Zip_code
        FROM   Student INNER JOIN Address
        ON     Student.Id=Address.Id;";
```

Comment: Did you mean to post to this question? The question was about products, and you posted about students. Also, the question was asked, and answered, 4 years ago.