# how can i select data from two tables in my sql

Tags: mysql

i have two tables named files, director. i want to select all data from director and select two columns from files this is code

```
$acc_no=$_POST['acc_no'];
$q="select * from files,director_recovery where account_no='$acc_no'";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join two tables mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536283/how-to-join-two-tables-mysql)

Comment: First of all give the table structure.It is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806097/how-to-fetch-data-from-two-tables-in-sql.

Answer (score 0):

For selecting data from 2 tables you can use `JOIN`

```
SELECT director_recovery.*, files.col1, files.col2 
  FROM director_recovery 
  JOIN files on files.account_no = $acc_no
```

I think this may help you